# How to translate the word "Chargebacks" into Brazilian Portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução

How can I translate the word "Chargebacks" in Brazilian Portuguese?

Google Translate gives "encargos" but "encargos" seem to refer mostly to additional fees and not like a charge back.

Comment: Can you include a definition of ChargeBak? Some use examples also can help.

Comment: "Chamamos de Chargeback a reversão de uma venda feita através de cartão de débito ou crédito, que pode acontecer por dois motivos:  o não reconhecimento da compra por parte do titular do cartão, e o outro quando a transação não obedece às regulamentações previstas nos termos do firmado com a empresa administradora do cartão." [chargeback de cartão de crédito](http://www.empreendedoronline.net.br/chargeback/)

Answer (score 3):

The most used term for those is `estorno` (plural: `estornos`), which happens when a customer disputes a charge and asks for their money to be returned. `Estorno` has a negative bias: it suggests a mistake was made.

Examples:

> [**O que é um estorno de pagamento?**](https://support.skype.com/pt-br/faq/FA341/o-que-e-um-estorno-de-pagamento)
>
> Estornos de pagamento acontecem quando você informa ao seu banco, operadora do cartão de crédito ou outra instituição financeira, como PayPal, que você contesta um pagamento feito por eles no seu nome, com base no fato de que o pagamento aconteceu sem o seu consentimento.

---

> [Agora, além de acessar suas vendas, você tem mais uma facilidade: o Relatório de Estorno, que demonstra as transações canceladas no mesmo dia em que foram realizadas.](https://www.userede.com.br/estorno)

---

However, when I used to live in the US, *chargeback* was a rather loose term, used in every situation where providers would give back the customer's money even when they were not at fault (for instance, when there was a price drop after the sale, and the retailer decided to return the difference). In Brazil, we call it `restituição` (plural: `restituições`).

Examples:

> [A Receita Federal liberou, nesta quinta-feira (08), o sétimo lote de restituição do Imposto de Renda Pessoa Física 2016. Esse lote vai contemplar 1,6 milhão de contribuintes com mais de R$ 2,3 bilhões.](http://www.brasil.gov.br/economia-e-emprego/2016/12/receita-libera-consulta-ao-setimo-lote-de-restituicao-do-imposto-de-renda)

---

> [**Existe possibilidade de restituição de taxa recolhida indevidamente?**](http://www.pf.gov.br/servicos-pf/produtos-quimicos/duvidas-frequentes/FAQ%20Taxa)
>
> Sim. O requerimento será analisado e, em sendo deferido o pedido, o processo será encaminhado à SENAD para que se faça a restituição.

Comment: chargeback tem dois sentidos: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/chargeback.html